# Does svn repo for 'release' tree have new auth requirement?

Tags: ros, svn, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release a new version of a previously released stack. I need to change an entry in release/distros/fuerte.rosdistro and distros/groovy.rosdistro to correct a git branch specification.

I UPed the latest 'release' tree from trunk, made the changes, and tried to commit. I *think* this used to just work, but I haven't done it in while: svn won't let me commit:

svn commit -m "Modified groovy.rosdistro and fuerte.rosdistro to pull different branches from robhum_utils repo."
Password for 'default' GNOME keyring:
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/release/!svn/act/bc7f360e-85e6-4d8a-b8da-2df6487a8432': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://code.ros.org)

Was there always a pwd/rsa auth, or is this new?

thanks,

Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74389/does-svn-repo-for-%27release%27-tree-have-new-auth-requirement?/) by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on 2013-08-26**:
Thanks, Tully, I'll try to get past the authentication barrier again, in the old place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been an announcement on the ros-release mailing list. I can't point to the archive since that is not yet available after the migeation to the OSUOSL.

```
We are continuing our migration of ROS services.  Today the release repository for dry packages has been moved from code.ros.org to Google code (https://code.google.com/p/ros-dry-releases/).

The new repository location requires every maintainer who wants to release dry packages in the future to re-do the setup instructions (http://www.ros.org/wiki/release/Setup/Machine):

* update the installed Debian package "python-rosrelease" to version >= 0.2.11

* get a fresh checkout of the release tools from their new location

* request to join the ros-dry-releases project by sending an email to ros-release@code.ros.org with your Googlecode login
```

If you are releasing ROS packages you might want to sign up for that mailing list since important release information like this is posted there.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0